# ffmpeg: Pick only AUDIO stream by metadata

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, streaming, metadata

I have a MP4 file which contains two audio streams with language tags `ger` and `fre`. The only video stream it contains is tagged as `eng`.

The ffmpeg documentation quotes:

```
To pick the English audio stream:

ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0:m:language:eng OUTPUT
```

In my case this does not work. It will instead output the only stream with tag `eng` (which is a video stream). This is consistent with: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1

However, is there an option to specify both

- the stream type (`v`, `a`, ...)
- *and* provide a metadata tag (e.g. `language:eng`)

for the same `-map` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly possible. The parser for this doesn't account for a second qualifier. Workaround is to use a pipe

```
ffmpeg -i IN -map 0:a -c copy -f nut - | ffmpeg -i - -c copy -map 0:m:language:eng OUT
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What is "-f nut" for? In the second command, can positions of parameters "-c" and "-map" be switched?

Comment: `-f nut` sets the output format of the first command to the NUT container. It accepts most codecs and can be written to a pipe, so I chose that. Yes, you can swap the order of `c` and `map`.

Comment: How would I also include the video stream of the input file in the output file?

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -i IN -i OUT -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy FINALOUT` next