# How to specify multiple ffmpeg stream specifier metadata tag keys?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

How do I specify multiple stream specifier metadata tag keys?

For example, this copies the video from the input to the output and only selects those audio tracks that are in English (there are two, one is Mono the other is Stereo):

```
ffmpeg -i "s1950e15 What's up Doc.mkv" -map 0:a:m:language:eng -map 0:v -c:v copy test.mkv
```

Similarly, this copies the video from the intut to the output and only selects those audio tracks that are Mono (there are two, one in English and one in French):

```
ffmpeg -i "s1950e15 What's up Doc.mkv" -map 0:a:m:title:Mono -map 0:v -c:v copy test.mkv
```

But how do I select the one audio track that is English and Mono?

This is what I want to do, if it were valid (it is not):

```
ffmpeg -i "s1950e15 What's up Doc.mkv" -map 0:a:m:language:eng:m:title:Mono -map 0:v -c:v copy test.mkv
```

I have tried the above and various combinations, none of which worked.

Here's the output from ffmpeg:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 's1950e15 What's up Doc.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmakemkv v1.16.7 (1.3.10/1.5.2) win(x64-release)
    creation_time   : 2022-05-05T00:52:29.000000Z
  Duration: 00:07:15.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3853 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 3070452
      DURATION-eng    : 00:07:15.802033333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 10449
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 167263690
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0100E0
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 7500000/0/0 buffer size: 1835008 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Mono
      BPS-eng         : 192000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:07:15.776000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 13618
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10458624
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0180BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:2(fre): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Mono
      BPS-eng         : 192000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:07:15.776000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 13618
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10458624
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0181BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 192000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:07:15.776000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 13618
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10458624
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0183BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 192000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:07:15.776000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 13618
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 10458624
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0185BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480 (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2609
      DURATION-eng    : 00:06:17.441033333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 58
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 123096
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0120BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:6(fre): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2755
      DURATION-eng    : 00:06:55.912800000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 62
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 143280
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0121BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:7(spa): Subtitle: dvd_subtitle, 720x480
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 2704
      DURATION-eng    : 00:06:55.912800000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 64
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 140580
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0122BD
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:8(eng): Subtitle: subrip
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 150
      DURATION-eng    : 00:06:30.488000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 129
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 7356
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 0100E0
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.16.7 win(x64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-05-05 00:52:29
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, ffmpeg only checks the first metadata value specified. I'll put this on my ToDo to allow further keys.

Comment: Something like this actually, -map 0:a:m:language:eng:title:Mono, (without the repeated m:) more closely resembles a standard key/value list.

Comment: Do any work-arounds come to mind?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1237954/

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg does have a function where you can manually set your metadata to be incorprated in your video file.

`ffmpeg -i oldfile.mp4 -codec copy -metadata title="" -metadata album="" -metadata year="" -metadata container="" -metadata artist="" -metadata comment="" newfile.mp4`

1. You put in desired variables inside `""` for each metadata.  I.e.  `-metadata title="Favorite Memory" -metadata comment="my vacation trip in 2022"`
2. Instead of attempting to strip metadatas from the same file, run ffmpeg to make a new copy with your preferred metadata (be sure to delete old file after you run ffmpeg for new file)
3. It is important that you use `-codec copy` function as it tells ffmpeg only to copy the file and add your data into metadata to be incorporated in the new file.